# -DJANGO- My following function doesn't seem to work?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm making a twitter clone, but I'm stuck right now on the following and followed problem, I wrote the code that can enable users to follow and unfollow a user but it's not working. Even though everything seems to be right. I think the problem lies when the UserFollow view executes it should do the thing and then redirect but it doesn't redirect which doesn't complete the whole view, that may be the case.

Here is the models.py

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
   def all(self):
    qs = self.get_queryset().all()
    if self.instance:
        qs = qs.exclude(user = self.instance)
    else:
        pass
    return qs

   def toggle_follow(self, user, to_toggle_user):
    user_profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user) # (user_obj, true)
    if to_toggle_user in user_profile.following.all():
        user_profile.following.remove(to_toggle_user)
        added = False
    else:
        user_profile.following.add(to_toggle_user)
        added = True
    return added

   def is_following(self, user, followed_by_user):
    user_profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
        return False
    if followed_by_user in user_profile.following.all():
        return True
    return False




class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name = "profile")

    following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank = True,related_name = "followed_by") 

    objects = ProfileManager()
```

Here is the views.py

```
class UserProfile(DetailView):
       model = User.objects.all()
      template_name = 'accounts/user_detail.html'

def get_object(self):
    return get_object_or_404(User,username__iexact = self.kwargs.get('username'))

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(UserProfile, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    following = Profile.objects.is_following(self.request.user, self.get_object())
    context['following'] = following
    # context['recommended'] = UserProfile.objects.recommended(self.request.user)
    return context

class UserFollow(View):
       def get(self,request,username,*args,**kwargs):
         toggle_user = get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username)
         if request.user.is_authenticated():
             is_following = Profile.objects.toggle_follow(request.user, toggle_user)


         return redirect("accounts:detail",username=username)
```

Here is the template code for the follow and unfollow

```
 <a href='{% url 'accounts:follow' object.username %}'class="btn btn-info">
        {% if following %}Unfollow {% else %}Follow{% endif %}</a>
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to provide username with `{% url 'accounts:follow' %}`?

Comment: It was just a mistake I did here but I have provided it  on the real code.I have also eidted the link here.You can check

Comment: Can you provide sample view how you construct users loop, especially how you do `following` variable. Seems like manager is working fine.

Comment: Yeah the following variable is in UserProfile View.I have just updated the code.

Comment: Well you have syntax error in `if request.user.is_authenticated:`; apart from that everything is working just fine and triggers follow/unfollow button.

Comment: It's still not working.

Comment: I tried what you said to me but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a human mistake in urls

The urls was

```
url(r'(?P<pk>\w+)/follow/$',views.UserFollow.as_view(),name = 'follow')
```

It's actually

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\w+)/follow/$',views.UserFollow.as_view(),name = 'follow')
```

A carrot at the beginning